# How to upsert multiple records with Apex controller

Tags: apex, upsert, insert

This code is able to upsert a single record in salesforce. I want it to save multiple records by breaking the long string of dates contained in the `datesFromCalendar`. `datesFromCalendar` contains data like this `[5]|DEBUG|01/13/2015,01/20/2015,01/27/2015,02/03/2015,02/10/2015,02/17/2015,02/‌​24/2015,03/03/2015,03/10/2015,03/17/2015,03/24/2015,03/31/2015,04/07/2015,04/14/2‌​015,04/21/2015,06/10/2015`. Each date should be a separate record in salesforce with all the other information intact and one random unique `id` with each set of records. For example above mentioned dates will have same unique id(*any random string generated within the controller*) but each should have to be a separate record in salesforce. Below is the controller which is saving all dates as a string.

```
public with sharing class EventsPageController {
    public Event__c Event{ 
     get {
      if (Event == null)
        Event = new Event__c();
      return Event;
    }
    set;
  }
    public String datesFromCalendar {get; set;}
    public List<String> eachDt = new List<String>();

    public void EventsPageController() {
        Event = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c,Event_Description__c,Event_Type__c,Maximum_Attendees__c,Occurrence__c,Program_Name__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

    }

    public Event__c getEvent(){
        return Event;
    }

    public String[] eventDates(){

      list<String> EventDates = new list<String>();
      list<Event__c> eventList = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];

      for(Event__c event : eventList) {
           EventDates.add(event.EventDates__c);
      }
      return EventDates;
}

    public PageReference saveData(){
        System.debug(datesFromCalendar);            
        try {
            Event.EventDates__c = datesFromCalendar;
            upsert(Event);
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        // After Save, navigate to the default view page:
        return (new ApexPages.StandardController(Event)).view(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it can be implemented it by separate the data, put in the list then upsert list?

Comment: @unidha `dates` are coming from JS variable & assigned to `datesFromCalendar` in controller. I've an idea to split each date and assign it to an array. Then loop over array and do some logic of inserting/upserting multiple records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you have to do a split on the variable `datesFromCalendar` and you split it by comma `,`

```
  List<Event__c> events = new List<Event__c>();
  List<String> dates = datesFromCalendar.Split(',');
  String randomId = generateRandomString(5);
  for(String date : dates){
       Datetime dt = Datetime.parse(date); //Convert the string to a date
       events.add(new Event__c(
          GeneratedId__c = randomId,
          Date__c = dt,
          Event_Description__c = Event.Event_Description__c,
          Event_Type__c = Event.Event_Type__c));
          //and so on for the rest of the data you want to keep the same. 
  }
  insert events //Then you insert or upsert events
```

For the random id for a set of records you can generate a random string. So it will be the same for a set of dates and once inserted into the database you will also have a Salesforce unique Id.

```
  public static String generateRandomString(Integer len) {
    final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    String randStr = '';
    while (randStr.length() < len) {
       Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), 62);
       randStr += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
    }
    return randStr; 
  }
```

Here is the [split](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_split) method in the documentation.

Here is the [parse](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse) method in the documentation.

Here is the [random string](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/how-do-i-generate-a-random-string) generator from an answer on salesforce stack exchange.

Hope it helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: What about this data? `Event = [SELECT Id, EventDates__c,Event_Description__c,Event_Type__c,Maximum_Attendees__c,Occurrence__c,Program_Name__c FROM Event__c WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
` Will it be intact same with each record?

Comment: I'm little confused. randomId should be same for each batch of dates and the remaining data like `Event_Description__c,Event_Type__c,Maximum_Attendees__c,Occurrence__c,P‌​rogram_Name__c` also be the same for each date. The only thing that will be unique for each record will the `Id` that is an Autonumber.

Comment: Updated my answer. The randomId will be the same for this set of dates as I'm calling the method once and loop through the dates and assign the id to all of them.

Comment: Then you don't really need the random string generator, you should leave the auto-number in the standard Name field for your custom object and then just loop through the dates and make sure that you have the same data for each event.

Comment: No that is actually some weird requirement. :) I also want to delete them in group. Lets say the `randomId1` is a random id of a group of event dates. When I delete the `randomId1` all the dates linked with this specific id will be deleted. I'll post another question for this as this post is only serving one feature.

Comment: Ok, did my answer help ? Did you achieve what you wanted ? I'm happy to explain more

Comment: Yeah I'm implementing it within my controller. But I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Mihai I already created the `Event__c` instance at top in my controller. Do I need to recreate an object of `Event__c` in this line of your code `Event__c createdEvent = new Event__c();` ?

Comment: Your instance of Event__c will be used to store the event selected from the database so that you ensure that you have the same description, the attendees etc. I've updated my answer where you really don't need the createdEvent.

Comment: I'm new to salesforce. Can you please refer me to some great content to learn visualforce and Apex. Books, training videos anything that can help me. One resource is you, I bookmarked :)

Comment: I come from a C#/ASP.NET MVC background so most of the things I learned are from there. A good book is the Advanced Apex Programming http://advancedapex.com/ but I recommend reading it once you are comfortable with apex. Some good tutorials about VisualForce/Apex can be found here https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead. Plus lots and lots of practice, it will come with experience and browsing salesforce stack exchange ... a lot. You are on the good track!

Comment: There is a little issue in this code while updating an existing record it doesn't only update that record but also create few more new records. Which it shouldn't have to do. Do I need to put an `if(Id == null){//then try to upsert?}` Otherwise update the existing record only.

Comment: Have a look at the upsert operation here and how it works http://sforce.co/1Dl2oDn.

Comment: Let me understand better what you are trying to do. The constructor of the EventsPageController() will always select an Event__c record, the one that is visible in the VisualForce page. Now with those dates, what do you want to do? You want to insert all those dates as Event__c records? If you use the upsert method you will only update the Event returned in the constructor because that record is the only one who has in Id in Salesforce. That's how the upsert DML operation works, if it finds an Id, if not it will be inserted.