# Random 16 character ID needs to be generated

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

I need to generate 16 random characters in the marketing cloud, how can I achieve this?

How do I generate this into a barcode?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/how-do-i-generate-a-random-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a random string?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/how-do-i-generate-a-random-string)

Comment: Kal and Reshma, note that this question is related to Marketing Cloud, not Sales Cloud and Apex.

Answer (score 4):

The [GUID](https://ampscript.guide/book/guid/) AMPscript function returns a 36-character global unique identifier (GUID) string, with hyphens.

The following code block will:

1. generate a random GUID
2. Remove the hyphens
3. Output the first 16 characters (an alphanumeric string)

#### Code

```js
%%[
var @guid, @charString
set @guid = Replace(GUID(),'-','')
set @charString = Substring(@guid,1,16)
]%%

string: %%=v(@charString)=%%
```

#### Result

```
string: 7da0ebd70a5f457e
```