# Testing or writing a test class for random string generator class

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

How can we unit test a random string generator class of this given code. I do get 100% code coverage, but I feel like the test is not executed properly. Any solutions to this will be helpful.

Random string generator code:

```
public class token {
    public static String createToken(){
        final String chars = 'A';
        String token = '';
        Integer x = 1;
        while (token.length() < x) {
            Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
            token += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Test class code (100% code coverage) :

```
@isTest
public class tokenTest {
    @isTest static void createTokenTest(){
        String tok = token.createToken();
        system.assertEquals('A', tok, 'doesn\'t work');
    }
}
```

will adding the random generator part in to a method and passing values help? meaning i can send in the required chars and length to get the desired output.

**UPDATED** - after @Phil W's answer, point 3 mentioned in his answer is not included in the test class code, as checking if the code is unique is tested in another trigger.

RSG code:

```
public class token {
    public static String createToken(){
        final String chars = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUWXYZ123456789';
        String token = '';
        Integer x = 6;
        while (token.length() < x) {
            Integer idx = Math.mod(Math.abs(Crypto.getRandomInteger()), chars.length());
            token += chars.substring(idx, idx+1);
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

Test Class code:

```
@isTest
public class tokenTest {
    @isTest static void tokenLengthTest(){
        String tok = token.createToken();
        system.assertEquals(6, tok.length(), 'doesn\'t work');
    }
    @isTest static void tokenCharacterTest(){
        String tok = token.createToken();
        final String charsTest = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUWXYZ123456789';
        final String charsNotTest = 'OQV0I!@#$%^&*()_+,.\'][<>?';
        system.assert(tok.containsOnly(charsTest), 'Failed at checking given characters, meaning string has invalid characters');
        system.assert(!tok.containsOnly(charsNotTest), 'Failed at checking invalid characters, meaning string has invalid characters');
    }
}
```

Comment: I think actual randomized number difficult to predict, its better to use mock string

Comment: sure it might be hard to predict, but if i set char to AB and integer 1, it will either create A or B. Meaning i can write a system.assertEquals for both. Or even set char as A, it will only create A as the random number. So the test won't fail. but i cannot figure out how to write this. can you please help

Comment: I would think that you could check that the token conforms to your expectations: it is the correct length, it only contains the desired characters and that you get a different value n% of the time on average (where n depends on the length of number of options for each digit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be testing the results against a fixed set of options but rather that:

1. The token is the correct length
2. The token is made up of the correct characters
3. The token is different on average n% of the time where n depends on the token length and number of options per character.

Comment: wow thanks for this, never thought of it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

@Phil W's is the best answer, but if you had a fixed set of strings you wanted to test again, then you could use `Set<String>` and then use the `System.assert()` like so:

```
@isTest static void createTokenTest(){
    String tok = token.createToken();
    Set<String> validTokens = new Set<String>{'A','AB','B'};    // You could move this into the actual Token class as a static final variable
    System.assert(validTokens.contains(tok), tok + ' is not a valid token');
}
```